# Was "Muscle Beach Party" filmed at Paradise Cove or Topanga Beach?

Tags: film-location, muscle-beach-party

The IMDB entry for [*Muscle Beach Party*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0058384) (1964) says that the filming location was Paradise Cove.

> [image: IMDb screenshot stating Paradise Cove]

But a recent entry in the discussion area disputes this, saying that Topanga Beach is more likely...

> [image: IMDb screenshot stating Topanga Beach]

I have looked at Google Maps vis-a-vis the film and tend to agree that Topanga Beach fits the background more closely.

Was it an error? If so, why would they put a bogus filming location?

Or alternatively is it possible that both locations were used and only Paradise Cove was given credit?

Comment: ... or it could be an honest mistake... anyone can submit changes to IMDb... they do their best to confirm them but sometimes they can't... and they just add it in.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking about content on IMDb, which is off topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the obvious studio/int. ones:
the 1st scene (highway) was filmed on CA-1 in Castle Rock, Malibu (app. 34° 2'28.71"N 118°33'52.39"W - heading east).
The modern-architectural house seen on the hill is the Spencer House III (Malibu house). Due to the hillside to collapse it had to be demolished in 1975.

2nd scene (with turn CA-1 on Beach Drive - app. 34° 2'23.62"N 118°34'50.43"W) shows the old Topanga Beach community. 
A good pic/area view before the bulldozers came:

[image: black and white picture of a shore]

The club house and beach used to be at the west end on Topanga Beach Rd. while the gym looks like a set-build one – imho (app. 34° 2'18.59"N 118°34'56.53"W).
The landslides east and west of Topanga Canyon Blvd are in the background in the beach scenes when focusing east.
The houses and market have been demolished due to the State Park (source: [surfwriter.net](http://www.surfwriter.net/beforethebulldozers.htm)).

As for Paradise Cove, some of the int. scenes may have been shot there or it'd be a mistake.